# why am not getting data from firestore?

Tags: flutter

hello I have the list of categories in my firestore i want to fetch them in to a listview it only shows CircularProgressIndicator then after it disapear nothing comes on screen where  did get  wrong?

```
Expanded(
                        child: _appwidget.customeTextFormField(
                            hint: "Select category",
                            icon: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  showFancyCustomDialog(context,
                                      height: 500,
                                      width: 500,
                                      title: "Add / Select / Delete Category",
                                      widget: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                                          future: _services.category
                                              .doc("ProductCategories")
                                              .get(),
                                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                                              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>
                                                  snapshot) {
                                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                              return Text('error');
                                            }
                                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                              return Container(
                                                child:
                                                    Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                              );
                                            }
                                            
                                            return ListView.builder(
                                              itemBuilder:
                                                  (BuildContext context,
                                                      int index) {
                                                return ListTile(
                                                  title: Text(snapshot.data!["Categories"]
                                                      [index]["name"]),
                                                );
                                              },
                                              itemCount: snapshot.data!['Categories'] ==
                                                      null
                                                  ? 0
                                                  : snapshot.data!['Categories'].length,
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      addButton: Container());
                                },
                                child: Icon(Icons.list)))),
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tackle the condition in which you have data.
Just add `if(snapshot.hasData)` & *return* your **ListView.builder()**, because in other conditions you are not sure whether you have received the data or not.

```
return Expanded(
        child: _appwidget.customeTextFormField(
            hint: "Select category",
            icon: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  showFancyCustomDialog(context,
                      height: 500,
                      width: 500,
                      title: "Add / Select / Delete Category",
                      widget: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                          future: _services.category
                              .doc("ProductCategories")
                              .get(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>
                              snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Text('error');
                            }
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return Container(
                                child:
                                Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                              );
                            }
                            if(snapshot.hasData){
                              return ListView.builder(
                                itemBuilder:
                                    (BuildContext context,
                                    int index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    title: Text(snapshot.data!["Categories"]
                                    [index]["name"]),
                                  );
                                },
                                itemCount: snapshot.data!['Categories'] ==
                                    null
                                    ? 0
                                    : snapshot.data!['Categories'].length,
                              );
                            }

                            
                          }),
                      addButton: Container());
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.list))));
```

Comment: thanks i have done that but still the same thing happen the circulaprogressindicator is shown and disapear with no data fetched remember in _service.category i have this i mean this one.....  CollectionReference category =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Category");